# Trying to Draw a point cloud, just a single point in the center in opengl

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, glfw, glm-math

Trying to create a random point cloud in 2D. However, I've got this in the end for now : The background color + 1 single 'grey' point in the center. What might have gone wrong here?

- I try writing my own simple shader.
- Trying to compile shader by myself.
- All are supposed to be baby steps.
- Also what would be some tips of debugging these issues?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/norm.hpp>

/* SHADERS */

/* Vertex Shader */
const char *VertexShaderSource="#version 330 core\n"
"layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;\n"
"//layout(location=1) in vec2 da;//distance and angle \n"
"//layout(location=2) in vec4 color;\n"
"\n"
"out vec4 particle_color\n"
"uniform mat4 mvp;\n"
"int main(){\n"
"gl_Position = mvp*vec4(pos, 0.0,1.0));\n"
"//particle_color =;\n"
"}\n";
/* Fragment Shader*/
const char *FragmentShaderSource="#version 330 core\n"
"//in vec4 particle_color;\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"//layout(location=2) in vec4 color;\n"
"void main(){\n"
"color =  vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);\n"
"}\n";
/* SHADERS END */



// Particle
struct Point{
    glm::vec2 pos;
    // Create random color in GPU
    // unsigned char r,g,b,a;
    float distance;
    float angle;
};
static const int max_point_number=1000;
Point PointContainer[max_point_number];

int main()
{
    // Start GLFW
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to start GLWF\n";
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }   

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE,GL,FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Rotating Points", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Initialization of the window failed\n";
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Start GLEW;
    glewExperimental = true;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to start GLEW\n";
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwPollEvents();

    glClearColor(.0f,0.5f,0.5f,0.0f); // Black is the new orange


    // Camera
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f,800.0f, 0.0f,600.0f,-5.0f,5.0f); // In world coordinates
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0,0,-1), // Camera is at (0,0,-1), in World Space
    glm::vec3(0,0,0), // and looks at the origin
    glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around
    // No need to have depth test

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Build and compile shaders
    // Vertex Shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &VertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Fragment Shader
    int fragmentShader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &FragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Link Shaders
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Delete Shaders after Linking
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    for(auto &p:PointContainer)
    {
        p.pos.x =rand() % 800;
        p.pos.y =rand() % 600;
        std::cout<<p.pos.x<<" "<<p.pos.y<<"\n";
    }
    // Vertex Shader
    GLuint tPM = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvp");//mvp
    glUniformMatrix4fv(tPM, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);


    GLuint pointsVertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &pointsVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PointContainer), PointContainer, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Start with NULL, update with frames;
    do
    {
        // Clear the screen
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );   
        //glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_POINTS, 0, 2, max_point_number);
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsVertexBuffer );
        glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
        //glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
        glVertexPointer( 4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof( Point ), (void*)offsetof( Point, pos ) );
        //glColorPointer( 4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof( Vertex ), (void*)offsetof( Vertex, color ) );
        glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, max_point_number);
        glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
        //glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );     // Swap buffers

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

## Edit:

I edited the code, still gives the same result.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>`

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/norm.hpp>

/* SHADERS */

/* Vertex Shader */
const char *VertexShaderSource=R"(
#version 330 core
layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;

uniform mat4 mvp;

int main(){
gl_Position = mvp*vec4(pos, 0.0,1.0);
}
)";
/* Fragment Shader*/
const char *FragmentShaderSource = R"(
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color =  vec4(1.0f);
}
)";
/* SHADERS END */

// Particle
struct Point{
    glm::vec2 pos;
    // Create random color in GPU
    // unsigned char r,g,b,a;
    float distance;
    float angle;
};
static const int max_point_number=1000;
Point PointContainer[max_point_number];

int main()
{
    // Start GLFW
    if(!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to start GLWF\n";
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }   

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE,GL,FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Rotating Points", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Initialization of the window failed\n";
        getchar();
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Start GLEW;
    glewExperimental = true;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to start GLEW\n";
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwPollEvents();

    glClearColor(.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f); // Black is the new orange


    // Camera
    glm::mat4 Projection = glm::ortho(0.0f,800.0f, 0.0f,600.0f,-5.0f,5.0f); // In world coordinates
    glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0,0,1), // Camera is at (0,0,-1), in World Space
    glm::vec3(0,0,0), // and looks at the origin
    glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
    );
    glm::mat4 Model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model; // Remember, matrix multiplication is the other way around
    // No need to have depth test

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Build and compile shaders
    // Vertex Shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &VertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Fragment Shader
    int fragmentShader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &FragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Link Shaders
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Delete Shaders after Linking
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    for(auto &p:PointContainer)
    {
        p.pos.x =(rand() % 800)*-1;
        p.pos.y =rand() % 600;
        std::cout<<p.pos.x<<" "<<p.pos.y<<"\n";
    }
    // Vertex Shader
    GLuint tPM = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvp");//mvp
    glUniformMatrix4fv(tPM, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);


    GLuint pointsVertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &pointsVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PointContainer), PointContainer, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Start with NULL, update with frames;

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );
    glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), 0 );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

    do
    {
        // Clear the screen
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );   

        glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, max_point_number);


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either you've to use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) or a compatibility profile [context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) (`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);`)

Comment: Looks like you are programming in C++ because `glm::mat4` is invalid C language syntax.  Please update you tags and post.

Comment: The vertex shader doesn't even compile. A `;`is missing affter `out vec4 particle_color`, the return type of `main` has to be `void` and at the end of `gl_Position = mvp*vec4(pos, 0.0,1.0));` there is one `)` to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex shader doesn't even compile. A `;`is missing affter `out vec4 particle_color`, the return type of `main` has to be `void` and at the end of `gl_Position = mvp*vec4(pos, 0.0,1.0));` there is one `)` to many.

I recommend to use a [Raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```cpp
const char *VertexShaderSource = R"(
#version 330 core
layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main(){
    gl_Position = mvp*vec4(pos, 0.0,1.0);
}
)";
```

---

Since you use a core profile [Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) you've to use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). e.g.:

```cpp
GLuint pointsVertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &pointsVertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointsVertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(PointContainer), PointContainer, GL_STREAM_DRAW); // Start with NULL, update with frames;

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*sizeof(float), 0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( 0 );

do
{
    // Clear the screen
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );   

    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, max_point_number);


    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );
```

---

You've an orthographic projection from (0, 0) to (600, 800), so the view matrix has to be

```cpp
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0,0,1), // Camera is at (0,0,-1), in World Space
    glm::vec3(0,0,0), // and looks at the origin
    glm::vec3(0,1,0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
);
```

Note, with your view matrix the points are drawn at the left of the viewport, so you can't see them. The point would be drawn in in the rectangle from (0, 0) to (-800, 600).

---

Change the color of the points in the fragment shader. The red color is hardly to see on the green ground:

```cpp
const char *FragmentShaderSource = R"(
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color =  vec4(1.0f);
}
)";
```

---

I recommend to verify if the shader succeeded to compile by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml). e.g.:

```cpp
glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
if ( status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint logLen;
    glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
    std::vector< char >log( logLen );
    GLsizei written;
    glGetShaderInfoLog( vertexShader, logLen, &written, log.data() );
    std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

and the program succeeded to link by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml). e.g.:

```cpp
glGetProgramiv( shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
if ( status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint logLen;
    glGetProgramiv( shaderProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
    std::vector< char >log( logLen );
    GLsizei written;
    glGetProgramInfoLog( shaderProgram, logLen, &written, log.data() );
    std::cout  << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hello. So I fixed through your suggestions (Thanks for the rawstrings especially). However, it still fails and gives the same solution...  I added an edited version to question.

Comment: @sariug **1.** The shader is still not correct. `void main` rather than `int main`. There is no way around. Verify if the shader was compiled successfully. See the last section of the answer, which I've added right now). **2.** either you've to change the view matrix (like in the answer) **or** `p.pos.x =(rand() % 800)*-1;`, but not pose together.

Comment: Oh man. I always overlooked this shader check but I can now see the reason clearly. Thank you very much.